# SQL Query date as at today

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a large section of code

That produces the below output example:

[image]

What I want to do is change the output so for **Future scheduled value** highlighted in the output it would only show the amount from the date the script is run.

example  - all amounts would stay the same as they are overall total amounts adding up since the start of the job **BUT** the Future scheduled value would change depending on when you run the report.  *so if you ran it today it is 1000 but tomorrow could be 300 etc etc*

I have selected the bits of code that reference this part as below:

```
 DECLARE @futureplanned TABLE(
Jobid INT,
hours MONEY,
sale MONEY)


INSERT INTO @futureplanned
(
    Jobid,
    hours,
    sale
)

Cast(ROUND(isnull(fp.sale,0),0) as INT) [Future scheduled value**],

LEFT JOIN @futureplanned fp on fp.jobid=job.jobid
```

Is this possible?

All help and advice much appreciated.

Comment: Isolate the logic for this column.  If after this exercise you still have questions, come back and be specific.

Comment: edited to try and make more sense